# WEB-INF folder is not creating in Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am creating a Spring Boot application, using Spring Initializr, But the folder structure is bit different, there is no `WEB-INF` folder, so where I will put the JSP files, shall I create the `WEB-INF` folder manually?

Comment: Don't use JSP files with Spring Boot or embedded containers. Use something like Thymeleaf instead. Why? JSP has severe limitations when using with embedded containers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We need to create the WEB-INF folder manually in spring boot application. Follow these steps:

1. Select main folder as highlighted below.

   [image]
2. Right click and create a folder with name **webapp**.
3. Now right click on **webapp** folder and create **WEB-INF** folder.
4. Now similarly create a **view** folder (or any other name you like) inside WEB-INF folder to keep all the JSPs.
5. Below should be the folder structure after doing above steps.

   [image]

Comment: This is the only way I could figure out to create WEB-INF folder and put jsp files. Spring boot project never creates any WEB-INF folder automatically.

Comment: I followed Telusko tutorials and he is also creating a webapp folder inside src-main. I guess your answer is ok then.

Comment: I want to use WEB-INF folder with Jar build. Is it possible?

Comment: @devPrakash, Its not possible because "mvn package" command generates the jar file for spring boot application which creates only BOOT-INF and MATA-INF folder inside the jar and ignores all other folders you create in the project including WEB-INF also.

Answer (score 4):

Dumping the jsp files in `src/main/webapp` folder worked for me, both with or without WEB-INF. I followed the exact project structure mentioned in

1. [mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/)
2. [springboottutorial](http://www.springboottutorial.com/creating-web-application-with-spring-boot)

Answer (score 3):

Usually the web files will go into the resources folder with spring boot.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: ok, suppose  greeting.jsp  is inside  the src/main/resources/templates/greeting.jsp, then how to configure the view resolver  . @Craigwar

Comment: add the settings (locations) to the application.properties `spring.mvc.view.prefix: /resources/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp`

Comment: Tried with adding those configuration in application.properties but still not working .

Comment: As long as you have the correct jars included it should work. You can also follow this guide which does add the WEB-INF directory back in. https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use jsp over thymeleaf? Tymeleaf, as in the original example link, is the recommended technology for spring boot web apps (well, all the guides use it anyway!)

Comment: use thymeleaf instead.

Comment: Is the resource folder a private folder like WEB-INF and not accessible by the public when the application is live?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. To solve this, You need to change in your **pom.xml** from **jar** to **war**, and do the following...

```sh
cd "my_project"
mvn clean package
java -jar my_project.war
```

And everything workout.

Answer (score 1):

**Inside:**          src/main/resources/application.properties

**Add this line:**   spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/view/

**Knowledge Source** watch 5 minutes: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35EQXmHKZYs&t=3333s) Start at: 55:33